# What are all the 1PI gluon 3-point function Feynman diagrams at 1-loop?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics

As an exercise in renormalization, I want to calculate the divergent part of the gluon 3-point function and gluon 4-point function matrix element. What are all the 1PI one-loop Feynman diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

These images are what I believe to be all of the diagrams.
[image]

[image]